# Differential equations, chemical reactions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, chemistry

> A chemical substance $A$ changes into substance $B$ at rate $\alpha$ times the amount of $A$ present. Substance $B$ changes into $C$ at rate $\beta$ times the amount of $B$ present. If, initially, only substance $A$ is present and its amount is $M$, show that the amount of $C$ present at time $t$ is
>
> $$M+M\left ( \frac{\beta e^{-\alpha t}-\alpha e^{-\beta t}}{\alpha - \beta}\right ) \tag{ 1}$$

So $a_0=M, b_0=0$ and $c_0=0$. Now I was doing some research, and found out that in these kinds of computations, the rate which amount of substance is decreasing over time are these solvable (by me) differential equations

$$\frac{dA}{dt}=-\alpha A \implies a_0e^{-\alpha t} = Me^{-\alpha t}\tag{2 }$$
$$\frac{dB}{dt}=-\beta B \implies b_0e^{-\beta t}\tag{3 }$$

The rate which the substances change formulas are these (they have something to do with the movement of particle in viscosious fluid)

$$\frac{dB}{dt} = \alpha A \implies b_0+a_0(1-e^{-\alpha t})\tag{ 4}$$
$$\frac{dC}{dt} = \beta B \implies b_0+a_0(1-e^{-\beta t})\tag{5 }$$

But I do not know how to move further to the final formula. Thanks for help in advance!

**EDIT**
B from the answer:

$$ke^{-\beta t}-\frac{M\alpha e^{\beta t - \alpha t} e^{-\beta t}}{\alpha - \beta}\tag{6 }$$

Do not know what to do with $k$ now, and I cannot substitute a like in previous step.

If I put $k = b_0 = 0$ and simplify then, it becomes

$$-\frac{M\beta e^{\alpha t}}{\alpha - \beta}$$

Doing $C=M-(A+B)$ will result in

$$M-M e^{-\alpha t}+\frac{M \alpha e^{-\alpha t}}{\alpha - \beta}$$

I am still missing something.

Comment: From (2) and (4) A+B is constant, and, from (3) and (5) B+C is constant. Is that correct? Is A+B+C constant?

Comment: You made a mistake. Use the formula for $B$, compute $B(0)$, set it to $0$ to get $k$

Comment: Again, in the second term of the expression of $B$, group the exponentials together and simplify.

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

Since you have $A\to B\to C$, I suppose that the kinetic model is $$\frac{dA}{dt}=-\alpha A$$ $$\frac{dB}{dt}=\alpha A-\beta B$$ $$\frac{dC}{dt}=\beta B$$ (remember that $B$ appears and disappears).

Integrating the first equation is simple. Using the initial condition, you obtained $$A=M e^{-\alpha  t}$$ which is perfectly correct. So, the second equation write $$\frac{dB}{dt}=\alpha M e^{-\alpha  t}-\beta B$$ which is not very complex and I let it to you.

For $C$, the problem is simple if you notice that $$\frac{dA}{dt}+\frac{dB}{dt}+\frac{dC}{dt}=0$$ which implies that, at any time $t$, $A+B+C=M$.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Hello and thank you. I have successfully integrated the B part, and it almost looks like the final result, but I still cannot come up with the final step. Could you please provide one more hint?

Comment: You are very welcome ! Could you show the result you got for $B$ ? For $C$, use the use my last trick : at any time $C=M-(A+B)$.

Comment: I added the result to the question. I think I got something!

Comment: You must use the condition $B(0)=0$. Is it better ? SImplify the expression you got.

Comment: It looks better, but I still struggle with it.

Comment: Look at my last comment. Do not set $k=0$; compute $k$ from $B(0)=0$